# TinyTex from RStudio Rmarkdown knitting to pdf. "Approximately" sign in ggplot annotate throws error

Tags: pdf, r, knitr, rmarkdown, tinytex

Reproducible example:

```
require(ggplot2)    
myggplot <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=1:2), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() 
z <- 16.9
myggplot <- myggplot + annotate(geom="text", x= 1.5, y=1.5, hjust = 0,  vjust = -1,
                                                label= paste("p ≈ ",z, " (Log-rank)"),
                                                color="black", size = 5)
myggplot
```

The plot, including the ≈ sign renders perfectly in RStudio and also in the output of my .Rmd document chunk. But when I try to knit to pdf, I get the error

> LaTeX Error: Unicode character ≈ (U+2248) not set up for use with
> LaTeX.

I have very little knowledge of LaTex - would anyone have a solution to this that would work with both ggplot and TinyTex pdf?

==========
Including (failed) tex code as requested:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
TRUE
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={ggplot},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{ggplot}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}2023-11-01}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{myggplot }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}} \FunctionTok{ggplot}\NormalTok{(}\FunctionTok{data.frame}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{x=}\DecValTok{1}\SpecialCharTok{:}\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{y=}\DecValTok{1}\SpecialCharTok{:}\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{), }\FunctionTok{aes}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{x=}\NormalTok{x,}\AttributeTok{y=}\NormalTok{y)) }\SpecialCharTok{+} \FunctionTok{geom\_point}\NormalTok{() }

\NormalTok{z }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}} \FloatTok{16.9}

\NormalTok{myggplot }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}}\NormalTok{ myggplot }\SpecialCharTok{+} \FunctionTok{annotate}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{geom=}\StringTok{"text"}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{x=} \FloatTok{1.5}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{y=}\FloatTok{1.5}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{hjust =} \DecValTok{0}\NormalTok{,  }\AttributeTok{vjust =} \SpecialCharTok{{-}}\DecValTok{1}\NormalTok{,}
                                            \AttributeTok{label=} \FunctionTok{paste}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"p ≈ "}\NormalTok{,z, }\StringTok{" (Log{-}rank)"}\NormalTok{),}
                                            \AttributeTok{color=}\StringTok{"black"}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{size =} \DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{)}


\NormalTok{myggplot}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\includegraphics{ggplot_rmd_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-2-1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: arrange that `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2248}{\approx}`  is added to the preamble of the generated latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the swift response. What does "preamble" mean in this context? I have tried to put the above both in the YAML header and the chunk but I get  `Error: unexpected symbol in "\DeclareUnicodeCharacter"`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show your resulting TeX code in your question?

Comment: Update: I put what @DavidCarlisle suggested in header-include: but it still does not knit: `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.123 ...\StringTok{" (Log{-}rank)"}\NormalTok{),}

Try to find the following text in ggplot_rmd.Rmd:
  ...\StringTok{" (Log{-}rank)"}\NormalTok{),} 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in ggplot_rmd.Rmd `

Comment: @Mensch, not entirely sure what you mean. I have an rmd file and get a pdf out. Was it the above error message you meant?

Comment: oh you are not in math mode, try `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2248}{\ensuremath{\approx}}`

Comment: @Reader123 R is generating a latex file to generate the pdf, you could show the latex as most of us won't have R

Comment: I tried the new code, @DavidCarlisle, but it does not even start knitting then: `Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 6, column 4 found character that cannot start any token at line 6, column 4' . I'll try to find where the latex file is...

Comment: sorry it's impossible to debug fragments of error messages in comments, show the full small generated file in your question

Comment: Tex code added.

Comment: tex stops on line 97 with `TRUE` which is just text that would typeset TRUE which is not allowed in begin document. It seems that the generation went wrong somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I made three changes as noted in comments, there were two errors in the file, and I swapped the image to one I had.  See `%%%HERE`

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2248}{\ensuremath{\approx}}

  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
%%%HERE
%%%%%%%?????????????????????????????TRUE
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={ggplot},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{ggplot}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}2023-11-01}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{myggplot }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}} \FunctionTok{ggplot}\NormalTok{(}\FunctionTok{data.frame}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{x=}\DecValTok{1}\SpecialCharTok{:}\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{y=}\DecValTok{1}\SpecialCharTok{:}\DecValTok{2}\NormalTok{), }\FunctionTok{aes}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{x=}\NormalTok{x,}\AttributeTok{y=}\NormalTok{y)) }\SpecialCharTok{+} \FunctionTok{geom\_point}\NormalTok{() }

\NormalTok{z }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}} \FloatTok{16.9}

\NormalTok{myggplot }\OtherTok{\textless{}{-}}\NormalTok{ myggplot }\SpecialCharTok{+} \FunctionTok{annotate}\NormalTok{(}\AttributeTok{geom=}\StringTok{"text"}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{x=} \FloatTok{1.5}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{y=}\FloatTok{1.5}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{hjust =} \DecValTok{0}\NormalTok{,  }\AttributeTok{vjust =} \SpecialCharTok{{-}}\DecValTok{1}\NormalTok{,}
                                            \AttributeTok{label=} \FunctionTok{paste}\NormalTok{(}\StringTok{"p ≈ "}\NormalTok{,z, }\StringTok{" (Log{-}rank)"}\NormalTok{),}
                                            \AttributeTok{color=}\StringTok{"black"}\NormalTok{, }\AttributeTok{size =} \DecValTok{5}\NormalTok{)}


\NormalTok{myggplot}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

%%%HERE
\includegraphics{example-image}

\end{document}
```

The main change, for the error in the title is to declare the character (just for pdflatex, not lualatex) as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2248}{\ensuremath{\approx}}
```

inside the `\ifPDFTeX` branch

Comment: Thank you very much, @DavidCarlisle, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test now with TinyTeX, but at least with vanilla TeX Live 2023:

[image: MWE]

**`.qmd`** file (do not use the .Rmd extension):

````
---
format: pdf
pdf-engine: lualatex
mainfont: FreeSerif
monofont: LiberationMono
keep-tex: true
lang: en
classoption: twocolumn
---

```{r}
#| include: false
z <- 16.9
```

The  "almost equal to" symbol (U+2248) can be typeset in Rmarkdown (or the newer Quarto)  as plain text (≈) or verbatim text  (`≈`) declaring the character to `pdflatex` as showed in other answer, or alternatively, as showed in this  \texttt{\jobname.qmd} using `xelatex` or `lualatex` with  some appropriate font.

If you see the "≈"  symbols in both cases, also will apear in R verbatim  inputs and outputs texts: 

\dotfill{}

```{r}
paste("p ≈",z, " (Log-rank)")
```

\dotfill{}


Or outputs in plain text: \fbox{`r paste("p ≈",z," (Log-rank)")`}

\newpage{}

But the true problem is that while you can use "≈" in label plots for a standalone image made with a R console, or some R script, when made inside a  `knitr`ed document there are some problem with font metrics of the  $\approx$ character, so the result will be: 

```{=tex}
\fbox{\makebox[\linewidth]{
```
```{r} 
#| echo: false
#| warning: false

plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste("p ≈",z, " (Log-rank)")) 

```
```{=tex}
}}
```

(... or munch worse, if you do not omit the warnings.)

However, using the `tikz` device, you can pass  the `\approx` command to plot labels, avoiding this problem, and moreover, the plot will have now the \LaTeX{} look and feel:


```{=tex}
\fbox{\makebox[\linewidth]{
```
```{r} 
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| dev: tikz

plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste("p \\ensuremath{\\approx}",z, " (Log-rank)")) 

```
```{=tex}
}}
```

If show in your code `\\ensuremath{\\approx}` instead of just  `≈` is an issue, you can always make and fake input chunk with the options  `echo: true` and `eval: false` and then true input chunk with the contrary options.
````

**Note**: If you curious about why I am using sometimes `{}` after  commands that do not need any arguments, this is because when embedded in Quarto texts, that highlight better that commands in editors with syntax highlight, help also to algorithms of LaTeX-markdown recognition (sometimes failed when they are not into explicit `{=tex}` or `{=latex}`  chunks), or  to prevent lost the space after some macro as `\LaTeX`.